# Simple way in Plone 4 to gather views/adapters in a registry/registries?

Tags: registry, plone, zope, grok

Searching for a way to keep a registry of views and named adapters in Plone 4 in a purely ZCML or grok manner, without making `registerSomething(myClass)`.

For example, if I have a main product, which needs a vocabulary of names for all named (multi)adapters of certain nature. The product can provide a couple of adapters, but other adapters can come from other products (third party), which should not be the main product's dependency.

The obvious way is to make some kind of registry, like PloneArticle's one for keeping track of page models (`registerArticleModel(MyPageModel)`), but I hope there is a cleaner way.

The question is, is there purely ZCML/grok way to achieve the registry effect? This way, when the third party product makes it's own adapter available, the "registry" would automatically pick it up and show in a vocabulary. For example, by querying component system for all adapters with certain signature.

Of course, the "registry" should not be persistent. Main product will use fallbacks in case of missing adapters/views.

Performance is not an issue, but linear search through all adapters for compiling vocabulary is not acceptable solution.

UPDATE:
to make this more concrete, consider the following use case with views:

```
  <browser:page
  name="content-item-plain"
  for="*"
  class=".content_item.ContentItem"
  permission="zope2.View"
  layer="my.model.browser.interfaces.IMyModelLayer"
  template="templates/content_item_plain.pt"
  />

  <browser:page
  name="content-item-another"
  for="*"
  class=".content_item.ContentItem"
  permission="zope2.View"
  layer="my.model.browser.interfaces.IMyModelLayer"
  template="templates/content_item_another.pt"
  />
```

...

In the template:

```
<-- config/layout may contain '@@content-item-another' or '@@content-item-plain' 
from the vocabulary -->

<tal:def define="layout config/layout"
     <metal:item use-macro="context/?layout/html" />
</tal:def>
```

Where context is almost any content type.

Does this approach make sense? If it does, how can I find all those view names for the dictionary?

Comment: This is exactly what the Zope component architecture is designed to solve, but it is unclear as to what you are asking. Did you read the available documentation?

Comment: I have not found answers in the documentation. My question could be boiled down to if there exist a method (say, "findAllMultiAdapters") for finding all suitable named adapters: component.findAllMultiAdapters((IA, IB), name="*")

Comment: Actually, there is more to it. Please, take a look at the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have probably overlooked the following part in the zope.component docs http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.component

> Sometimes you want to know all adapters that are available. Let's say
>   you want to know about all the adapters that convert a German to a US
>   socket type:
>
> ```
> >>> sockets = list(zope.component.getAdapters((bathroomDE,), IUSSocket))
> >>> len(sockets)
> 3
> >>> names = [name for name, socket in sockets]
> >>> names.sort()
> >>> names
> [u'', u'dvd', u'shaver']
> ```

This seems to answer my question on the (non-multi) adapters' side. Views aren't covered still.

I can make view-to-view named adapter, but then I can't override `index` with `template` in the ZCML, which is important...

Comment: getAdapters() can get multi-adapters (such as views) too, with some limitations (only one named adapter per interface).